# Como cancelar una orden en Futuros Binance?

Tags: python, binance

Usando la librería de Binance `python-binance` estoy intentando cancelar una orden de futuros mediante Python. Estoy usando la función `futures_cancel_order` y añadiendo de parámetro el `symbol` y el `orderId` que he recibido de `futures_get_open_orders`.
Sin embargo me da error cuando lo intento:

**CODE**

```
cancel = client.futures_cancel_order(symbol = "DENTUSDT")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mpaya5/Documentos/Crypto/dent/positions.py", line 144, in <module>
    check_delete()
  File "/home/mpaya5/Documentos/Crypto/dent/positions.py", line 119, in check_delete
    order_cancel = client.futures_cancel_order(symbol="DENTUSDT", orderId = int(order1))
  File "/home/mpaya5/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 5337, in futures_cancel_order
    return self._request_futures_api('delete', 'order', True, data=params)
  File "/home/mpaya5/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 333, in _request_futures_api
    return self._request(method, uri, signed, True, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mpaya5/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 309, in _request
    return self._handle_response(self.response)
  File "/home/mpaya5/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 318, in _handle_response
    raise BinanceAPIException(response, response.status_code, response.text)
binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-2011): Unknown order sent.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el parámetro orderId es mandatorio en esa instrucción, se debe requisitar de la siguiente manera:

```
miordencancel = client.futures_cancel_order(symbol = "DENTUSDT",orderId=TuOrden)
```